# GDAL 2.1 DelaunayTriangulation Give bad results (sometimes)

Tags: gdal, geos

I am using the latest stable release of GDAL 2.1.  When I add vertexes to a polygon in a loop sometimes it does not return the correct results.  If I put those same values in hard coded, the right result is returned.

```
OGRPolygon     poly;
OGRLinearRing  ring;
OGRLineString  line;
for(pVert = Vertexes.begin(); pVert != Vertexes.end(); pVert++)
    ring.addPoint(pVert->X, pVert->Y);
poly.addRing(&ring);
poly.closeRings();

OGRMultiPolygon* poOutPolys = (OGRMultiPolygon*)poly.DelaunayTriangulation(0.0001, 0);
int NumOut = poOutPolys->getNumGeometries();
```

This results in the following values in the debugger watch window, but only 2 triangles returned (there should be 3 with a 5 vertex polygon):

```
-       ((*(OGRSimpleCurve*)(&(*(OGRLineString*)(&ring))))).paoPoints,5 0x07b1a330 {x=2771.5700000000002 y=4720.0959999999995 } OGRRawPoint *
+       [0] {x=2771.5700000000002 y=4720.0959999999995 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [1] {x=2774.0639999999999 y=4722.5940000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [2] {x=2589.1100000000001 y=4722.5940000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [3] {x=2590.6970000000001 y=4721.0050000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [4] {x=2640.1439999999998 y=4720.0490000000000 }    OGRRawPoint
```

If is use the following code, 3 triangles are returned.

```
OGRPolygon     poly2;
OGRLinearRing  ring2;
ring2.addPoint(2771.570, 4720.096);
ring2.addPoint(2774.064, 4772.594);
ring2.addPoint(2589.110, 4722.594);
ring2.addPoint(2590.697, 4721.005);
ring2.addPoint(2640.144, 4720.049);
poly2.addRing(&ring2);
poly2.closeRings();
OGRMultiPolygon* poOutPolys2 = (OGRMultiPolygon*)poly2.DelaunayTriangulation(0.0001, 0);
int NumOut2 = poOutPolys2->getNumGeometries();
```

Debug watch window:

```
-       ((*(OGRSimpleCurve*)(&(*(OGRLineString*)(&ring2))))).paoPoints,5    0x07b1a0e8 {x=2771.5700000000002 y=4720.0959999999995 } OGRRawPoint *
+       [0] {x=2771.5700000000002 y=4720.0959999999995 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [1] {x=2774.0639999999999 y=4772.5940000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [2] {x=2589.1100000000001 y=4722.5940000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [3] {x=2590.6970000000001 y=4721.0050000000001 }    OGRRawPoint
+       [4] {x=2640.1439999999998 y=4720.0490000000000 }    OGRRawPoint
```

What is going on?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: OK.  I after staring at this all day, I exported the polygon to wkt and compared them.  The hard coded values were different on the second point.  Now it consistently fails when importing wkt:

    "POLYGON ((2771.57 4720.096,2774.064 4722.594,2589.11 4722.594,2590.697 4721.005,2640.144 4720.049,2771.57 4720.096))"